# How to handle account creation in Parse with log-ins from multiple social media platforms?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I was wondering if there was a convenient way for users who sign up for an account with my app utilizing a Parse backend (they would essentially be a PFUser) to log in on one social media platform, say Facebook, then log out and log back in with another social media platform (like LinkedIn) without creating two separate accounts. When and how could this be handled?

Comment: I don't think that's possible given that there is only one column to save the social media login auth data in User class. How do you propose that you will link the social media hooks to your one PFUser given those constraints and problems in tracking it to right PFUser for different social accounts? But well that's just off the top of my head. I think I saw a similar question here but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Parse provides an API for linking Facebook and Twitter users to a Parse user account. The relevant sections of the documentation are listed below:

- [FaceBook integration](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users)
- [Twitter integration](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-twitter-users)

So if a user logs in using a Twitter login or a Facebook login, they can be linked automatically to a Parse user and saved to your Parse backend.

The other option is to link an existing Parse user, that you have created, to Facebook or Twitter.

In general, social logins are managed by an access token that is returned when a user logs in to the service. The SDKs to support this login are usually available from the service provider. Therefore, linking a service that is not directly supported by Parse, such as LinkedIn, would require storing this token in your Parse database and linking it to your Parse user.